# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function when importing/exporting on ES6 with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I just wanted to ask you this because I tried to look for some inforomation and I wasn't able to fix this.

I have a projecto in which I use webpack tu make a bundle and babel to use ES6, but I face a problem which I don't understand and I cannot solve.

I have a class like this (Component.js):

```
export default class Component {
  ...
}
```

A file with a constant like this (Constants.js):

```
const arrHead = [...];
export { arrHead }
```

And another class this way (Table.js):

```
import { arrHead } from "../constants";
import Component from "../core/Component";

class Table extends Component {}
```

The problem is: When I tried to import this class and constant in the Table.js file, I get an error at the beginning of the file telling me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`

[image]

This is happening with both importing the class and the constant array, and I don't know why it's happening, maybe some hint?

I'm using webpack to make a bundle.js, maybe does it soome relation to this? Thanks to all!

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible repo?

Comment: What do you need to check, I can paste you some other code, because I don't have it in a repo yet.

Comment: I’d like to check all things you set up since sometimes it’s hard to say anything if we don’t have a full picture